# extracting masked image from original without black background

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a saliency map which indicates which part of an image is the most salient. I've been trying to extract this salient part of the image from the original. Right now I'm doing:

```
img_thresholded=img.*repmat(saliency_map >= prctile(saliency_map(:),75),[1 1 size(img,3)]);
```

what this code achieves is:[image]

As you can see, the salient image extracted has a lot of black in the background, which is expecte, since the code above converts any non salient part to 0. My question is, how else can I do it so that I only get the salient image and no black backgrounds?

Comment: what do you mean by "no black background" ? the black background is there because your data has to be stored somewhere and that somewhere is of rectangular shape... if you do not care about the "geometrical" look of the information/image then you could just scan the whole matrix and remove the 0 valued indices

Comment: @Smash I'm thinking interms of a transparent image, where those 0's are removed. However, there is no guarantee that something in the image isn't black as well and I don't want to risk destroying that. Thus is my dilemma.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You already have what you need,
What is your next step? And I'll tell you what to do with the black background.

Comment: my next step is to get rid of the background, using a combo of all(img....)=[]. But like I said in the comments, I don't want to risk blotting out parts of the image that are actually black.

Comment: There are two separate issues here, if you have "real" black points in your images you can use something else like a "blue screen" (0, 0, 1) as "nothing", the second issue is the problem of bg showing up as black, which as I said is not an actual problem, and depends on your next steps.

Comment: There is a good chance you don't have any completely black pixels in your images if they are real photos.

Comment: I need this image for extracting SIFT descriptors so I don't want any of the background, black or blue screen. But you do have a point with the black pixel not being in real photos.

Comment: I guess your best bet is to cut your images based on a criterion drived from saliency maps into small rectangles, like from the peak of the map go until 3*std or something like that.

Comment: that seems like quite a bit of work, I'm more inclined to just remove all black pixels now.

Comment: again, what do you want to put in their "empty" place?

Comment: I'm guessing that without a filler for those empty spaces the image would become distorted in someway? In that case, how would I proceed with small rectangles? I'm essentially piecing together a non-geometric image out of small rectangles, wouldn't the final image from this also have empty spaces?

Comment: If I understand the whole thing correctly, your saliency map should have some sort of "scope" or scale and that tells you how large your rectangles would be. Let's say you are working on 1000X1000 images if faces, your saliency map (if you were to do detect features to be used for discriminating happy vs. sad faces) would be like 400X400 (something to capture mouth up to labial folds). If your use case does not necessitates that you keep the spatial structure of the pixels, by all means just remove the black pixels.

Comment: yea spatial structure is quite important for me since I'm using this for object recognition. So if I'm understanding you correctly you are recommending me to just make a rectangular approximation of the area defined by the saliency map? Basically just getting the smallest rectangle possible that fits most of the salient parts? I was thinking of something like that as well, but I feared that unneeded parts would get extracted as well.

Comment: Yes that is my suggestion, also you can have a neutral color, like a neutral gray (or the actual average value of all the pixels in your image and either use the mean or better than that use a random number chosen from a normal distribution around that mean and std). You can do more fancy things but I'd try these and see if they generate any artifacts then decide what to do next.